# Error launching composer-rest-server

Tags: ibm-cloud, blockchain, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I'm working on this tutorial https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/tutorials/developer-guide.html

On the section Generate REST API when i'm going to launch the composer-rest-server by running the command

```
composer-rest-server
```

I got the following error:

```
/home/../.nvm/versions/node/v6.11.4/lib/node_modules/composer-rest-server/node_modules/lodash-compat/internal/LodashWrapper.js:1
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { pf ZCALLBACK win32_open64_file_funcA (voidpf opaque,const void* filename,int mode)

SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
at createScript (vm.js:56:10)
at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:97:10)
at Module._compile (module.js:542:28)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
at Object.<anonymous> (/home/../.nvm/versions/node/v6.11.4/lib/node_modules/composer-rest-server/node_modules/lodash-compat/chain/lodash.js:2:21)
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: What's your OS and version -  are you using Windows?? What's your docker version? Is this a local composer REST server instance? What was the command used to spin up the composer rest server? Did you manage to create a local .bna file (so that your trade network was generated?)?

Comment: Two questions:                                                                                         
     First:Did you npm install inside the project folder and deployed inside dist folder ?Second:Are you able to ping using this command here in bracket(composer network ping -n my-network -p hlfv1 -i admin -s adminpw)?If you are getting command succeeded in both the steps ,try starting fabric instance using ./startFabric.sh followed by ./createFabric.sh in fabric-tools folder .

Answer (score 0):

Try to install the package globally using:

```
npm install -g composer-rest-server
```

Answer (score 0):

First uninstall composer rest server

```
npm uninstall composer-rest-server
```

second install

```
npm install -g composer-rest-server@0.20.5
```

version according to your requirements then after run composer-rest-server it will ask a few questions
like as follow. Provide detail

```
composer-rest-server
? Enter the name of the business network card to use: admin@your-network-Name
? Specify if you want namespaces in the generated REST API: never use namespaces
? Specify if you want to use an API key to secure the REST API: No
? Specify if you want to enable authentication for the REST API using Passport: No
? Specify if you want to enable the explorer test interface: No
? Specify a key if you want to enable dynamic logging: No
? Specify if you want to enable event publication over WebSockets: Yes
? Specify if you want to enable TLS security for the REST API: No
```